# How to use value element in xpath for selenium-java?

Tags: xpath, selenium-java

I used this xpath locator:
//table/following::div[text()='value']/preceding::span[@class='x-grid-checkcolumn'][1]"}

on the page i scripted as:

```
public void selectTestPlan(String value) {
            String[] path = {ChatTestingPagePath2.ChatTestManagement.TEST_PLAN_CHECKBOX[0].replace("{value}", value),ChatTestingPagePath2.ChatTestManagement.TEST_PLAN_CHECKBOX[1]};
            click(path);
        }
```

but it always failed, it says that it was unable to locate the element.

Hoping for your response.

Thank you!

However when changing the value in specific value like this:

//table/following::div[text()='**Testing**']/preceding::span[@class='x-grid-checkcolumn'][1]"}

and use the page as:

```
public void selectTestPlan() {
            String[] path = {ChatTestingPagePath2.ChatTestManagement.TEST_PLAN_CHECKBOX[0], value),ChatTestingPagePath2.ChatTestManagement.TEST_PLAN_CHECKBOX[1]};
            click(path);
        }
```

it will passed the automated test.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public void selectTestPlan(String value) {

        String path = "//table/following::div[text()='%s'] preceding::span[@class='x-grid-checkcolumn'][1]";

        click(String.format(path, value));
    }
```

I hope it helps!